# domxpath regex wildcard

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I'm writing a PHP script to pull div id's that are incremented within their id
example:

```
<div id="tag_1">content</div>
<div id="tag_2">content</div>
```

so basically, how do I write query domxpath with a wildcard like so:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[@id='tag_.*']");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use starts-with

```
"//div/@id[starts-with(., 'tag_')]/.."
```